# async await seems to have no effect on my function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I'm trying to push new data to my posts array and display it on the client with DOM manipulation. The 1st two elements get displayed as expected but the 3rd element is not getting displayed while I'm using the async/await keyword

```
const posts = [
  {
    title: 'Post One',
    body: 'This is post one'
  },
  {
    title: 'Post Two',
    body: 'This is post two'
  }
];

const getPosts = () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    let output = "";
    posts.forEach((post, index) => {
      output += 
        `<ul>
          <li>${post.title}</li>
        </ul>`
    })

    document.getElementById('heading').innerHTML = output;

  }, 1000);
}

const createPosts = (newPost) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    posts.push(newPost);
  }, 2000)

}

const newPost = async () => {
  try{
    await createPosts({title: 'Post Three', body: 'This is post three'});
    getPosts();
  }
  catch{err =>  console.log(err)}
}


newPost();
```

Comment: `createPosts()` is not returning a promise, you can't `await` it. Why does `createPosts()` use `setTimeout()`?

Comment: To push the data in my array after 3sec and then start DOM manipulation.

Comment: So it needs to return a promise that's resolved in the timeout function.

Comment: remove the setTimeout in createPosts() and make the post var not constant

Comment: Yes, thank you Barmar. Indeed the createPosts has to return a promise to work. I found the problem. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`createPosts()` needs to return a `Promise` that's resolved after the timeout, so you can await it.

```
const createPosts = newPost =>
  new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => {
    posts.push(newPost);
    resolve();
  }), 2000));
```